# Units and zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ and in general

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ are polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ with degree $0$ or $1$.

I.e. $\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{x}, \overline{x+1}\}$

$\overline{0} = \overline{x^2 + 1} = \overline{x + 1} \cdot \overline{x + 1} \implies \overline{x + 1}$ is a zero divisor

The units are the elements coprime to $\overline{x^2 + 1}$ which are $\overline{1}, \overline{x}$

This is the case in this trivial quotient ring, I am just wondering if it is the case in general? That is -

1. The zero divisors are all possible multiples of the irreducible factors of the quotient?
2. The units are all the elements that are coprime to the quotient?

Comment: Try thinking about the Euclidean algorithm and what it tells you for coprime polynomials.

Comment: It says that if $a, n$ coprime there exists $x, y$ such that $ax + ny = 1$. Modding by $n$ we have that $\overline{a}\overline{x} = \overline{1}$. So $a$ coprime $\implies a$ a unit?

Comment: And conversely, if $\bar{a}\bar{x}\equiv \bar{1}$, then $1-ax\in (x^2+1)$, meaning that $a$ and $x^2+1$ are coprime.

Comment: @LASV Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).